# Was Ottoman control a factor in the voyage taken by Christopher Columbus?

Tags: europe, ottoman-empire, asia, christopher-columbus

I am reading *A People's History of The United States* by Howard Zinn and it says after the Ottomans [conquered Constantinople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople) they controlled the land routes to Asia, making sea routes necessary. But I cannot find any other sources making this claim. Is it true?

Comment: Weird that you can't find backup for that. My memory is that every grade school World history book I saw used to say the same thing back when I was a kid (OK, that's nearly half a century ago, and we had old books at my school, but still...)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How significant was the Fall of Constantinople as an event leading to the Age of Exploration?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20769/how-significant-was-the-fall-of-constantinople-as-an-event-leading-to-the-age-of)